# Displaying content of JSON file in ion-item with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using the following code to load data from a JSON file and display it in a `ion-list` as `ion-item`s, but it does not work. I cannot figure out what's wrong with the way I'm doing it.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"; 
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

/**
 * Interface for a single Call entry
 * A Call always has a 'name:string' and a 'telephone:string', any 
 * other attribute is optional.
 */
export interface Call {
    name:           string,
    telephone:      string, 
    description?:   string,
    street?:        string,
    postal?:        string
}

/**
 * Interface for a list of Call entries 
 */
export interface CallList {
    calls: Call[];
}

/**
 * Class for a page that shows Call entries
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'page-calls',
    templateUrl: 'calls.html'
})
export class CallsPage {

    callList: CallList;

    /**
     * Constructor of CallsPage
     * @param http 
     */
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.loadCalls('assets/json/calls.json');
        // console.log(this.callList); // does not work, just gives "undefined"
    };

    /**
     * Loads list of calls from a json file
     * @param filePath: Path to file that shall be loaded
     */
    loadCalls(filePath: string) {
        return this.http.get<CallList>(filePath).subscribe(
            data => { 
                this.callList = data; 
                // console.log(data); // works
            }
        );
    };
}
```

`calls.json` contains

```
[
{"name": "Police","telephone": "110","description": ""},
{"name": "Fire","telephone": "112","description": ""}
]
```

This is the template `calls.html` to be used

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>

        <ion-title>Calls</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="call in callList">
            {{call.name}}: {{call.telephone}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

But when I open this page in my app, the following appears in the console: 
`Unhandled Promise rejection: _co.call is undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:`. 
I guess something is still wrong with the way I'm trying to import the data from JSON. The line in the constructor, which is commented out, just gives `undefined` in the console. Yet when I do the same in the `.subscribe` call it prints out the data. So I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Comment: besides that it should be `ngFor` like established, your error seems to point to some `emergencyCall`, which we cannot see in your code...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **`angular`** syntax **`ngFor`** instead of **`ng-repeat`** which is **`angularjs 1.x`** syntax

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let call of callList">
    {{call.name}}: {{call.telephone}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was wrong, too. Now a test list like `<ion-item *ngFor="let n of [1,2,3]">{{n}}</ion-item>` works. But the data I actually want to display still seems to be `undefined`, and so it does not work, either. But now one problem is out of the way.